# Squid dstdom_regex not working

Tags: proxy, centos, squid

I want to deny all URL beginning by iso, in squid 3.2.3
So, I've put in squid.conf:

```
  acl torrent_sites dstdom_regex -i iso
  acl music_sites dstdom_regex -i music
```

and my http control like:

```
  http_access allow localhost
  http_access allow localnetp1
  http_access deny torrent_sites localnetp1
  http_access deny music_sites
  http_access deny ftp_request
  http_access deny localnetp1 norm_conn
  http_access deny all
```

but i can enter to the page isohunt.com, why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a slightly different method.  I'm using the standard squid.conf file but changed the `#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16` to my network IE: "192.168.1.0". Then search the conf file for the section that reads,

```
#deny_info TCP_RESET ads".
```

just **above** the TCP_RESET line, add the following.

```
acl torrent dstdom_regex "/path/torrent_sites.txt"
http_access deny torrent
acl music dstdom_regex "/path/music_sites.txt"
http_access deny music
```

Now create 2 text files (`/path/torrent_sites.txt` and `/path/music_sites.txt`) that contain your URLs in the following format.

```
(^|\.)isohunt\.com$
(^|\.)thepiratebay\.org$
(^|\.)torrentz\.com$
```

etc.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/squid3 restart
```

or however else you want to restart it and everything should be good to go!

Blacklists can be found here: [squid ACL examples & blacklist to download](http://dobo.us/squid.html)